# mysql access without webserver (ex. Apache)

Tags: mysql, apache, webserver, database-connection

I was wondering if there is a way to access a database service on a remote computer without having a webserver installed on that computer?

Does MYSQL DBMS provide some interface (port) which can be connected directly to, or is a webserver (that forwards the communication) mandatory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL can be access by default on port 3306.
Normally this port will be blocked by the firewall though, as it's not good practice to have your DB server accessible to the outside world.

If you want to access a remote database via the command line you can use the [mysql client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql.html).

If you're doing this over the internet you should probably use a tunnel or VPN for security.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to MySQL using ODBC. Default Port 3306

Answer (score 0):

As they said. You can connect with mysql using the (default por 3306). You may use mysql client, or the ODBC, JDBC, or ADO.Net interfaces. There are connectors for most of the main programing languages.

If you are looking for a user-friendly tool to use mysql like PHPmyAdmin you may like  MYSQL GUI Tools
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html